# Prestashop Add custom column called "number of products", displaying quantity ordered from "ps_order" table

Tags: prestashop, admin, product-quantity

I am trying to find a way to display product ordered quantity in **Orders** Page, in back-end of a Prestashop v.1.6.1.9 installation.

I already managed to add 2 custom columns by overriding **AdminOrdersController.php**. I have added phone_mobile and custom notes in this manner:

```
$this->fields_list['phone_mobile'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('Phone Number')
    );

$this->fields_list['note'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('Notes')
    );
```

Any way I can override this file to show the quantity ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let me clear one thing; quantity ordered is not getting stored in `{DB_PREFIX}order` table; it is stored in `{DB_PREFIX}order_detail` table.

To add `total_qty` total quantities ordered you need to get quantity from `{DB_PREFIX}order_detail` table and to achieve this you can do below things in your override.

```
<?php
/**
 * @override AdminOrdersController
 */

class AdminOrdersController extends AdminOrdersControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();        
        $this->_select .= ', (SELECT SUM(od.product_quantity) FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail` od WHERE od.id_order = a.id_order GROUP BY od.id_order) as total_qty';

        $this->fields_list = array_merge($this->fields_list, array(
            'total_qty' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Number of products'),
                'havingFilter' => true,
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

You can add your fields like `phone_mobile` and `custom_notes` accordingly.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, it worked like expected for my case. Guess I was querying the wrong table to get the info. Thank you!